# Running an android app on phone

Tags: android, rest, samsung-mobile

I have a Cordova project in spring-rest for server side and client side i am using commandline tool for client side building.On client side AVD runs and is able to access my server side code. I want to test the same app on my android phone.

I have enabled USB Debugging on my phone and i am on same network as my computer..i am able to see the app installed but its not accessing the server side code on my eclipse and fetching the results.

please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Which URL did you use to access the server? Some `localhost` in there?

Comment: Yes localhost there.Works fine with that,with IP address also its working on system.On phone its not running

Comment: No. A client can not function in an emulator using localhost as host name. Please explain better what you did.

Comment: Which ip address/hostname exactly did you use 'on the system'? And which on the phone?

Comment: I am using my IP address to run on emulator.To run the app on phone i am running my server app on eclipse and i am on same internet network as my system.

Comment: 192.168.0.101 for system